# Macbook showing unusual storage uses

Tags: macos

I'm using macbook retina mid 2014 with storage capacity 128GB. When i check my storage **About This Mac > Storage**, its showing uses of movies occupying 3.96GB. I check all folders individually but i can't find a single video file.

And also why the "other" section occupying 56.04 GB of storage.
Here is the screenshot.
[image: Storage]

Comment: If you open Spotlight (with Cmd-Space) and enter "kind:movie" does it find any files?

Comment: @root thank you... With ur help i'm able to find the movies and delete it. Now the movies showing only 234 Mb. Is there any way to find this remaining portion of movies also??? And any help for 'other' section 

Comment: Check out Apple's [page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202867) on _Other_. As Steve Chambers said, use OmniDiskSweeper (free) or some other tool like DaisyDisk (paid, but convenient visualization of consumed space) to analyze where all your space is going and then drill down.

Answer (score 0):

When I have run across puzzling lack of space on my Macs I have used the freeware [OmniDiskSweeper](https://www.omnigroup.com/more/) that catalogs the disk and sorts by size. there are others out there that do similar things, this article [talks about three.](http://osxdaily.com/2016/04/29/best-disk-storage-analyzers-mac/)

One of those should help you discover, in greater detail, what is consuming the space on your Mac.